# Why can't delete MYSQL folder in program file (Local Disc C)

Tags: mysql-workbench

I want to uninstall MYSQL workbench in my PC.after uninstall & while deleting MYSQL, it shows the action cant be completed because of the folder or a file in it is open in another program,Close the folder or file and try again .

I always try to delete folder but I couldnt.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't delete the folder because mysql service is using it.**

Mysql workbench, by default installs mysql as a service, which is the recommended way to run mysql.

> On Windows, the recommended way to run MySQL is to install it as a Windows service, so that MySQL starts and stops automatically when Windows starts and stops. A MySQL server installed as a service can also be controlled from the command line using NET commands, or with the graphical Services utility. Generally, to install MySQL as a Windows service you should be logged in using an account that has administrator rights.

From [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-service.html)

On Windows, if you have used an installer to install something, you should uninstall it from **Add Remove Programs**.

Not only will its installer stop the service, and remove all files but also tidy up registry entries.